# Checking if a list of objects contains an object whose property has a specific value

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<Contract>`.

Each Contract has an 'ObservableCollection'

```
class Contract
   {
   private ObservableCollection<Operation> listOpAss;
   public ObservableCollection<Operation> ListOpAss
   {
      get { return listOpAss; }
      set
      {
         if (this.listOpAss != value)
         {
            this.listOpAss = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("ListOpAss");
         }
      }
   }
   ...
}

class Operation
{
   public long ID{get;set;}
   public long ID{get;set;}
   public long ID{get;set;}
}
```

For example,I want to get the list of all contracts, that has an Operation whose ID=7, is there a way to do that using linq?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov please read the question, it is not a duplicate at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var result = contractsList.Where(x=>x.ListOpAss.Any(y=>y.ID == 7)).ToList();
```

Basically we filter lists by using the [Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2) method and passing there a predicate. In this case the predicate should be based on checking if an operation exists in the corresponding list of each contract. For doing so, we use the Any method.

The [Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.7.2) method return trues when the predicate we pass is true. In this case we require to check if there is any `Operation` in the `ListOsAss`, whose `ID` is equal to 7.

Comment: thanks, perfect to me. One question, how can I say my question is NOT a duplicate, it has been marked as duplicate, but I think he marked as duplicate because he didn't read it...

Comment: You are welcome. You can't do something more than the comment you have already written. I will vote this question to reopen.